# Avoiding ArrayList Concurrency with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have an ArrayList object:

```
    List<Sample> dataList = new ArrayList<Sample>();
```

This has a list of Sample objects. Sample contains a long timestamp and a double value primitives.

I have a program that will act on these via multiple threads. I have a thread that will prune the data 1/hr. The prune takes roughly 2 minutes to complete (low end embedded system and a lot of data). It calls the following function to do this:

```
 public synchronized void prune(long timestamp)
    {
        Iterator<Sample> it = dataList.listIterator();

        while (it.next().getTimestamp() < timestamp)
        {
            it.remove();
        }       

    }
}
```

I also have dynamic data being updated to this array via another thread at 1/sec. Depending on the data being added it can call one of the two following functions:

```
  public synchronized void addPointData(ArrayList<Sample> a)
    {

            a.addAll(dataList);
            dataList = a;

    }

    public synchronized void addPointData(Sample a)
    {

            dataList.add(a);
            if (dataList.size() > 0 && pruneLock == 0 && dataList.get(0).getTimestamp() < (System.currentTimeMillis() - 90000000L) * 1000000)
            {
                dataList.remove(0);
                startTimestamp = dataList.get(0).getTimestamp();
            }       
    }
```

In so far running this, I haven't had any concurrency exceptions and I don't believe I've had any lost data. I'm concerned about lost data if the pruner makes the Add functions wait for it. Can anyone explain why I haven't had an exception? Should I be doing this a different way?

Comment: It look like you're really only using this as a queue.  There are plenty of correctly concurrent queue structures.

Comment: Hey Louis, this is part of a Trending application. The data in the array list can be expanded in certain instances and locked where the pruner will have to wait 24 hours before touching it again.

Comment: Yes, and so what?

Comment: Also having memory constraints (in memory storage), what exactly is wrong with using an arraylist. Why would I use a queue instead?

Comment: Who says a queue is necessarily more expensive?  A queue is just significantly easier to get concurrency correct on.

Comment: I see. I figured grabbing items for a trend... this arraylist is holding 24 hours of 1/sec data. The user may request data from in the middle, the end, the whole 24 hrs, whatever. I figured accessing would be easier with arraylist

Comment: None of the methods you have here do that.  If that's actually the case, using a list may be necessary, though I'd note that `remove(0)` from an `ArrayList` that big is going to be super expensive, as it's O(n).

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't think it would be applicable. Indeed the main functions include these adds, prune, and getData. Primary focus is getting data quickly and I just want to ensure I'm not losing data or having a concurrency problem.

Comment: @Tacitus86 Are the requests for data based on the timestamp as the criteria?

Comment: Yes, i basically have a loop iterate thru grabbing all Samples w timestamp > than T1 and < T2

Comment: What is `pruneLock`? I see it used but not defined.

Comment: I expect calling [`ArrayList::removeRange`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeRange-int-int-) would be much faster though I’ve not examined the implementation. Are your inputs guaranteed to be added chronologically?

Comment: Prune lock is an integer that is set when external data is added to the list and needs to be held for 24 hrs. It gets set to 24 and every time the pruner runs at once an hour it decrement it.

Comment: Yes. Chronological.

Comment: @Tacitus86 You should show that pruneLock code, as that might be another concurrency risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one else has answered... good comments, and good points about how to store your data more efficiently. But that aside, if the operations you included are the *only* operations that modify the list, you have the code correct to prevent concurrent modification exceptions or loss of data. All operations that modify are synchronized. You'll have blocking situations, but you won't ever have concurrent modifications.

Making the add functions wait for the prune to complete is exactly what should happen. As long as there's no other reason the add functions can't wait, it's fine.

As commenters pointed out, though, there are faster ways to go about this that may reduce the overall wait time. Given that you're always deleting by time, if you know things are added in time order, you can significantly optimize the process. If you're sorted by time and require that, there are definitely better options (or if you can choose to sort on insert). There are some uses of Java 8 streams that can parallelize and provide some different processing options.

But short answer is that you've got locking where needed to prevent issues.

Comment: Since the prune and add are on a schedule (1/sec for add) if its waiting, it wont prevent data from being gathered, it will just hold it from being written correct?

Comment: Correct. That's the behavior of synchronized, to block and wait until no one else has it locked.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have put `synchronize` on everything that touches your `ArrayList` will ensure that you don't get concurrency issues.

On the other hand, your performance will stink. Everytime a prune happens, everything that needs the data list will stop.

You have two big performance issues. The first is that `remove` on `ArrayList` is very inefficient. Everytime you remove something from the middle it has to shuffle down everything above it to fill the gap. The only reason this is even tolerable is because it uses `System.arrayCopy` which is a low level super-optimised call and is quick. But if you do a lot of deletions you are shifting down your tail for every deletion.

One thing that is not clear is whether your Samples are sorted. If they are in order and you can identify the start and end of where you need to prune, you should use `removeRange` to remove the block in one go.

If your list is sorted and you are removing from the front you are better off using an `ArrayDeque` as this efficiently supports removing from the front and the back.

Assuming that is not the case and the timestamps are randomly distributed in the array, it might be quicker to fill the gaps as you go with something like:

```
j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
    Sample s = dataList.get(i);
    if (s.getTimestamp() >= timestamp) {
        dataList.set(j++, s);
    }
}
removeRange(j, dataList.size());
```

I haven't tested it, but maybe you get the idea.

Or maybe there is some Java 8 cleverness to do the same thing more elegantly.

But this is still going to lock your whole data structure while the prune is happening, so you could consider pruning in smaller chunks. This will synchronize your data for smaller periods of time and lead to shorter delays.

Comment: It is sorted. And i only remove from the back end (oldest). Usually via remove (0) or a chunk off the back via prune.

Comment: Typical case the remove (0) in the add function will take care of most items so prune wont have to do anything. In the odd case it does, it will be a big chunk of samples. Anywhere up to 50% of the arraylist

Comment: If you mean the first element (element 0), then you are better usind a Deque implementation (e.g., ArrayDeque). This allows efficient removal from both ends. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thats the typical PRUNE functionality, not the entire program. You can and will be adding singles on the front, chunks on the front, iterating through and getting elements between timestamp x and y. The last one there i think its not best to use a queue. Do you agree?

Comment: If you are adding elements a the front (meaning element zero) then you should definitely use a Queue. There isn't much to be lost by using an ArrayDeque as there is little overhead above an ArrayList.